# Where is KeysAsync method in StackExchange Redis

Tags: c#, concurrency, redis, stackexchange.redis

Looking at IServer interface in StackExchange.Redis library, I found that there is a `Keys` method which will run `KEYS` or `SCAN` command in redis depending on the server capabilities. But then I noticed that there is no async method which can provide `SCAN` functionality asynchronously.

In my situation, I am optimizing a web API application which depends on redis's `SCAN` for finding previously cached values of a request. Giving some massive load on it, I noticed that StackExchange.Redis is giving timeout exceptions and tracing it further I noticed that it is raising these exceptions because there is a highly concurrent situation which each of these calls becomes synchronous by `Keys` method eventually. Hence this synchronous calls will timeout. So there is my question, why Keys method does not have an async version? And if I can resolve this situation better, what can be done?

**PS:** For getting a glimpse of what am I doing in that web API consider the following code which will simulate my situation:

```
Partitioner.Create(0, 500000, 10000).AsParallel().Select(async range =>
{
    for (var i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        var keys = _server.Keys(0, "ab*<cd*efg>*", 50).Select(x => (string) x);
        await Task.WhenAll(keys.Select(key => _database.StringGetAsync(key)));
    }
})).Wait();
```

Comment: Don't really get the concept... caching usually works via direct lookup for a hash that reflects your parameters, why do you need to walk through all keys? However SCAN is only available since redis 2.8.0 and KEYS is not intended to be used in production => https://redis.io/commands/KEYS

Comment: @sui I want to query multiple possible cached values. There is many application for that. Also, I don't intend to use `KEYS` in production I want to use `SCAN` command.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have solved my problem using the raw execute api, In case any one else is having this problem, here is what worked for me.

```
Partitioner.Create(0, 500000, 10000).AsParallel().Select(async range =>
{
    for (var i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        var keys = await _database.ExecuteAsync("SCAN", "0", "MATCH", pattern).ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult(((RedisResult[]) ((RedisResult[]) x.Result)[1]).Select(y => (string) y));
            }).Unwrap();
        await Task.WhenAll(keys.Select(key => _database.StringGetAsync(key)));
    }
})).Wait();
```

And of course, it is not that clean. Unless anyone else has a better solution this is what I am going with.

Answer (score 0):

There is an async version. I'm not exactly sure when it was added but I've been using it since whatever version of `StackExchange.Redis` was the latest version in early 2020.

Here is the link to the interface in their repo: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/StackExchange.Redis/Interfaces/IServer.cs#L343